# Calling function with interval but until some time passed Iphone

Tags: iphone, nstimer, scheduler, intervals

I need to make a call every .025 seconds over a duration of 30 seconds. Here is my .025 second timer.

```
NSTimer* myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.025 target: self
                    selector: @selector(GetScreen:) userInfo: nil repeats:YES ];
```

How can I restrict this to a duration of 30 seconds?

Comment: what do you mean by only during 30 sec? Do you want this only once?

Comment: Coz now when i am calling that what i wrote this function will be called every 0,025 till the app will be switched off. i want to call it every 0,025 but during 30 sec then i dont want to call this function so what i rly want to do is call it 30*0,025 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want it to continue for 30 seconds then you would just make a member variable to increment until it hits 30 seconds then you turn off your timer:

```
CGFloat timerTotal_;

//initialize it where you create your timer
timerTotal_ = 0.0f;

//every time your GetScreen: is called
timerTotal_+= .025;

if(timerTotal_ > 30)
{
    [myTimer invalidate];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you are trying to wait until some condition has been met, don't use a timer to do that.** Use a delegate pattern, or notification/observer or semaphore, etc.

If you want to call `GetScreen:` (which should probably be `getScreen:` by normal Obj-C convention) once, after 30s, use this:

```
[ NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30.0 target:self selector:@selector( getScreen: ) userInfo:nil repeats:NO ] ;
```

Comment: I want to call getScreen 0,025*30 times but with exact interval of time ... that what u wrote is not the answer ;/